# How are dependencies in multiple log4j.properties files managed under Maven?

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have a maven project with several dependencies and use `log4j.properties` to control output. In some cases the same class may be referenced in different property files with different parameters. Is there a defined protocol for "overriding" properties or does it depend on the order in which packages are loaded?

(I am locating all `log4j.properties` directly under `src/main/resources` - is this the correct place?)

UPDATE:
I have accepted @Assen's answer as it makes sense though it doesn't make the solution easy. Essentially he recommends excluding log4j.properties from the jar. In principle I agree, but it puts the burden on the user to control the output and most of my users don't know what Java is, let alone properties files.
Maybe there is a way of renaming the properties files in each jar and using a switch (maybe with -D) to activates the properties.

Comment: Can you post some example? Yes, the most appropriate place for your application resources is `src/main(or test, if they belong to test phase)/resources`.

Comment: I'm using code that subclasses the Apache PDFBox project (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) . (Out of my control, used through maven).  PDFBox can have voluminous DEBUG/INFO output if certain types of document are processed (it's reporting unusual conditions). I have two packages, PDF2SVG (which depends on PDFBox and has a log4j.properties to control its output and that of PDFBox). It also uses (my) library EUCLID, which also has a log4j.properties. The next package, SVGPlus, depends on PDF2SVG and has its own log4j.properties with stricter control. I find that I cannot control the properties used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often have similar discussions on projects. I thing log4j.properties is typically something you want to keep *out* of the application, and not pack it in a war and deliver it together with the code. Logging configuration:

- is environment specific. When you write the application, you simply can't define the  appenders that will be desired, file locations etc.
- its lifecycle is totally different than the application's. After an application is deployed, logging properties can be changed several times a day. Redeploying the application shouldn't override your last logging settings.

Why package logging configuration together with your code then? I usually keep somewhere a configuration folder, with soubfolders like 'dev', 'test-server-01', 'macbook-john' etc. Each subfolder contains list own copy of log4j.properties. None of them is included in the build artifact - jar or war.

When deploying, one of thuse subfolders is delivered separately. For the test server 1, this would be the content of test-server-01 subfolder. Dependng on the application server used, thers is a different trick tu put some files on the classpath.

When developing, I take care to set one of those subfolders on the path. When John develops on his macbook, he might want to put 'macbook-jihn' on the classpath, or create a new one. He can change logging settings and commit without conflicts.

Comment: +1. I think you may be right that log4j.properties should not be included in the JAR file but welcome other experience.